# TestMethod coverage for merge variable

Tags: apex, code-coverage

is there any way to get code coverage for merge variables.

For example:

In Visualforce page I am using a string variable `myDescription` in value attribute.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!obj.myDescription}" rendered="true" />
```

In class MyObject :

```
public String myDescription {
        get {
            return getObjDescription(2);
        } 
        set {}
}

private String getObjDescription(Integer Level) {
        // TODO          
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to call the `getObjDescription(Integer Level)` method directly with `@TestVisible` annotation?

Answer (score 2):

You can test it simply by accessing the variable:

```
MyObject o = new MyObject();
System.assert('Expected message', o.myDescription);
```

This will test both the getter for myDescription as well as the private method.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is to call private getter from the test class you can use [`TestVisible`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm) annotation so that your private getter will visible to the test class and you can solve the code coverage issue. So simply apply the annotation to your getter as below.

```
@TestVisible
private String getObjDescription(Integer Level) {
        // TODO          
}
```

Then call the method from your test class as usual.

Comment: But this won't test `myDescription`...